# What maximum value of AUC optimism could still be allowed to confirm that logistic regression model does not overfit?

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap, auc, optimism

I am not sure how to define that a statistical model does not overfit based on a difference between bootstrapped AUC and AUC calculated on all training data. In the literature I saw 2 approches. The first one was to use Delong or analogous tests to confirm that the difference in AUC values is not statistically significant. The second approach was to use some threshold value between apparent and validated AUC values. For example, in an article "Modern modelling techniques are data hungry: a simulation study for predicting dichotomous endpoints" a small optimism is being defined as difference between the mean apparent AUC and the mean validated AUC <0.01.

How small AUC optimism value should be to consider a statistical model as not overfitting? Are there any guidelines?

Comment: Overfitting is a matter of degree.  There is no magic threshold.  That being said I often look at the calibration slope and use a 0.9 “threshold” as a rough guide to whether overfitting is acceptable.  But we really need to emphasize the overall closeness of an unbiased smooth calibration curve to the line of identity.